# Comparing two Occupancy Grids

Tags: navigation, simulation, stage, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to find a way of comparing two stage occupancy grids: the first one is generated by slam gmapping (published on the "map" topic) and the second comes from the rasterization of the stage floor model (myModel.Rasterize(myRasterArray, this->width, this->height, cellwidth, cellheight) - see this page http://rtv.github.io/Stage/classStg_1_1Model.html). I managed to access both of these grids, and I generated both grids with the same height, width and resolution. Now, I am wondering if both grids possess the same coordinates; for instance, would comparing the cells at position (1,2) correspond to the same cell on both maps? If not, is there a way of superimposing both grids?

[Edit] I printed the occupancy grids obtained, and the two aren't even oriented in the same way (see picture here http://tinypic.com/r/x2ph5l/5). #1 is the slam map, #2 is the map extracted from the Stage model, and the image to the right is the bitmap used to build the Stage map (yes, a smiley face!). Note that the robot is wandering inside the white area, which explains why image #1 is just the inside of the smiley face. All in all, I need to find a way of aligning the grids... Please help?

[Edit2] I'm attempting to use the debug option of mapstitch which is supposed to "save the current_stitch.pgm and current_map.pgm, i.e. the stitched maps and the current map as seen on /map.", but there is nothing being outputted. Is this a bug? Here's my launch file:

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>  
  <node pkg="mapstitch" type="ros_mapstitch" name="ros_mapstitch">    
    <param name="debug" value ="true" />
  </node>  
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66825/comparing-two-occupancy-grids/) by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 343 on 2013-07-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Avonic](https://answers.ros.org/users/26092/avonic/) on 2016-02-26**:
So may I ask if you know a way to do things around - having two occupancy and compare them to get coordinates? Please advice me.
Thank you.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-27**:
@Avonic: that sounds like you have a different question. You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [mapstitch](http://ros.org/wiki/mapstitch) package.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-07-09**:
Thanks! That might be just what I needed! I'll keep you informed.

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-07-09**:
My map is not being transformed as it should; it seems like mapstitch isn't doing anything. Could it be because nothing is publishing on the world topic despite the fact that mapstitch is listening to it? Which node should be publishing on world? I'm using stage and there's no such topic as world.

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-07-10**:
I managed to publish the world used by stage on the /world and /align topics. However, mapstitch still doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a somewhat convoluted solution to my problem using the above answer. First, I used the map_saver to store my slam gmapping map. Then, I created a copy of map_saver that listens on the *world* topic instead of the *map* topic. I programmed a publisher publishing the real world map on the *world* topic. As a result, I have both my slam map and world map with the same size and resolution stored as pgm. However, they are not aligned. Hence, I modified the *get_stitch* function in *mapstitch.cpp* by commenting out *addWeighted*. That way, the first map can be aligned with the second without them being merged. With both maps aligned, I can compare them -I use Graphics Magick. I will post my code once it's cleaned up and commented.

However, I'd be curious to know how to make mapstitch work the way it's supposed to (using rosrun). I think that might produce more accurate results.

[Edit] Here is the code I use. It might not work out of the box so I haven't created a repo. Sorry if it's a bit messy, it was my first real c++ program.

generator.cpp:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <nav_msgs/GetMap.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h>
#include <navfn/navfn_ros.h>
#include <mapfetch.h> 

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    std::vector<uint8_t> realMap;     //Real world map.
    
    ros::init(argc, argv, "compare");   
    
    /*Publishers for the real map on the /world and /align topics.*/
    ros::NodeHandle nodeH;  
    ros::Publisher worldPub = nodeH.advertise<nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid>("world", 1000);
    ros::Publisher alignPub = nodeH.advertise<nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid>("align", 1000);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
        
    MapFetcher fetcher(argc, argv, argv[argc - 4]);     
    ROS_INFO("Map width: %d, height: %d, resolution: %g", fetcher.width, fetcher.height, fetcher.resolution);   
    
    /*Get the occupancy grid of the real map with the same 
    width, height and resolution as the gmapping map.*/
    realMap = fetcher.getGroundTruth();     
    
    //Convert the map to a standard ros occupancy grid.
    std::vector<int8_t> map;
    for(int i = 0; i < +realMap.size(); i++){
        if(+realMap[i] == 1){ //Occupied cell.
            map.push_back(100);
        }
        else if (+realMap[i] == 0){ //Free cell.
            map.push_back(0);
        }
        else{
            map.push_back(-1); //Unknown cell.
        }
    } 
   
   //Publish the occupancy grid.
    while (ros::ok()){
        
        nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid mapGrid;
        nav_msgs::MapMetaData metaData;
        
        metaData.resolution = fetcher.resolution;
        metaData.width = fetcher.width;
        metaData.height = fetcher.height;
        
        mapGrid.data = map;
        mapGrid.info = metaData;
        
        worldPub.publish(mapGrid);
        alignPub.publish(mapGrid);
    
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();      
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

mapfetcher.cpp

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <nav_msgs/GetMap.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h>
#include <navfn/navfn_ros.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <nav_msgs/MapMetaData.h>
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <rosgraph_msgs/Clock.h>

// libstage
#include <stage.hh>

#define USAGE "stageros <worldfile>"
#define BASE_POSE_GROUND_TRUTH "base_pose_ground_truth"

using namespace std;

class MapFetcher {
private:
    int argc;
    char **argv;
    char *fname;
    ros::Time sim_time;
    ros::Publisher clock_pub_;
    std::vector<ros::Publisher> ground_truth_pubs_; 
    rosgraph_msgs::Clock clockMsg;
    boost::mutex msg_lock;        
    ros::Subscriber mapSub;
    ros::Subscriber metaSub;
    Stg::Model *groundModel;
    
    /**Map data**/
    std::vector<uint8_t> realMap;
    std::vector<int8_t> builtMap;      
    void metaDataCallback(const nav_msgs::MapMetaData::ConstPtr& msg);
    void mapCallback(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid::ConstPtr& msg); 
    void setGroundTruth(); 
    
public:
    MapFetcher(int argc, char** argv, char* fname); 
    ~MapFetcher();      
    std::vector<int8_t> getSlamMap();
    std::vector<uint8_t> getGroundTruth();  
    float resolution; //Map resolution  
    unsigned int width; // Map width [cells]    
    unsigned int height; //Map height [cells]
};

//Constructor.
MapFetcher::MapFetcher(int argc, char** argv, char* fname) : 
    argc(argc), 
    argv(argv),
    fname(fname),
    resolution(0),
    width(0),
    height(0) {
        
    ros::NodeHandle node;
    
    //Get the slam map's occupancy grid and its metadata.           
    metaSub = node.subscribe("map_metadata", 1, &MapFetcher::metaDataCallback, this);               
    mapSub = node.subscribe("map", 1, &MapFetcher::mapCallback, this);
    width = atoi(argv[argc - 2]); 
    height = atoi(argv[argc - 1]);
    
    //Wait for the map data to be fetched.
    while(resolution == 0  && ros::ok){     
        ros::spinOnce();
        sleep(2);
    }
    
    //Set the real map.
    setGroundTruth();
}

//Destructor
MapFetcher::~MapFetcher(){  
    //DESTROY EVERYTHING BOOM
}

//Return the real map.
std::vector<uint8_t> MapFetcher::getGroundTruth(){
    return realMap;
}

//Return the map built by slam gmapping.
std::vector<int8_t> MapFetcher::getSlamMap(){
    return builtMap;
}

/**
 * HELPER FUNCTIONS
 * **/
 
//Get the occupancy grid for the gmapping map.
void MapFetcher::mapCallback(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid::ConstPtr& msg) {
        this->builtMap = msg->data;         
}

//Get the occupancy grid metadata.
void MapFetcher::metaDataCallback(const nav_msgs::MapMetaData::ConstPtr& msg) {     
        /*this->width = msg->width;
        this->height = msg->height;*/
        /*I changed the above two values to constants because executing this code
        when the slam map was not complete caused cropping issues.*/        
        this->resolution = msg->resolution;
}

//Set the real map as displayed on Stage.
void MapFetcher::setGroundTruth(){
    
    ros::NodeHandle node2;      
    struct stat s; //roscpp-related bookkeeping
  
    //Timing parameters. 
    sim_time.fromSec(0.0);
    node2.setParam("/use_sim_time", true);
    clock_pub_ = node2.advertise<rosgraph_msgs::Clock>("/clock",10); 
    ros::WallRate r(10.0);  
    
    // We'll check the existence of the world file, because libstage doesn't
    // expose its failure to open it. 
    if(stat(fname, &s) != 0){
        ROS_FATAL("The world file %s does not exist.", fname);
        ROS_BREAK();
    }       
    
    //Initialize libstage.  
    Stg::Init(&argc-1, &argv);  
    
    //Load the world.
    Stg::World *world = new Stg::World; 
    (*world).Load(fname);
    (*world).Start();   
    groundModel = (*world).GetModel(argv[argc - 3]);    
    
    //Rasterize the floor model.        
    uint8_t raster[this->width * this->height];
    Stg::meters_t cellwidth = this->resolution;
    Stg::meters_t cellheight = this->resolution; 
    (*groundModel).Rasterize(raster, this->width, this->height, cellwidth, cellheight);     
    std::vector<uint8_t> temp(raster, raster + sizeof(raster) / sizeof(raster[0]));     
    this->realMap = temp;
    
}
```

I also found out that the GIMP Image Registration Plugin works quite well where mapstitch fails.

---

Originally posted by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) with karma: 343 on 2013-07-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-07-11**:
I guess that's up to the darmstadt guys to explain. If you are interested I'd suggest opening a new question directly aimed at that.

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-07-11**:
I might do that if my results are not good enough. Thanks!

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-07-15**:
I asked the mapstitch author about my problem and received a reply here: https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/mapstitch/issues/1

**Comment by [sagi0910](https://answers.ros.org/users/28450/sagi0910/) on 2016-11-06**:
Can you please share your final solution ? and I'm  also interested on what metrics did you use to estimate the error after the alignment of the two maps .